# Why the title doesn't appear

Tags: python, pyqt

I wrote the following code but when I run the program only appears two letters of the main title. Anybody knows how to fix it?

```
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    #self.center()
    self.setStyleSheet("background-color: white")
    self.resize(1028, 720)
    self.setWindowTitle('GBLtda Database')
    label = QtGui.QLabel('GB DATABASE', self)
    label.setStyleSheet("font: 50pt AGENTORANGE") 
        label.move(20, 20)
```

Comment: When you change the font size, the whole label appears. Check at 10 point. I'm not sure why it blocks the top and bottom...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
label.resize(514, 360)
```

The first is the width in pixels, and the second is the height - you want the height to be at least 10% more than the font size, so 55 is the minimum number for that.
(obviously, change the values to suit what you like)

Answer (score 1):

Becase the label widgets does not resize.

You need to resize it using `resize` method after changing font.

```
...
label.setStyleSheet("font: 50pt AGENTORANGE") 
label.resize(label.sizeHint()) # <-----
label.move(20, 20)
```

Or, you can put the label inside the layout object.